# How to perform "ranking" (as in SAS or a "dense rank" as in SQL) in Deedle

Tags: sas, deedle, dense-rank

Sas has a procedure called [rank](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1hxon9vm350ikn19oeualfap8qy.htm) that assigns a "rank" to each row in a dataframe according to the position in an ordered set of a variable, ***kind of***; but the rank is not just the position: one has to tell the procedure how many groups use in the ranking. The rank is actually the group to which the row belongs.

In SQL terms, this is called a [dense ranking](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions#dense_rank).

Example (the salary variable is included for generality, but it is not used in this example):

Say we have this data frame:

[image: Original]

If we rank by age using 4 groups, sas would give us this:
[image: ranked]

It is easier to understand what happened if we sort the data by the variable we ranked:
[image: ranked and sorted]

Now we can see why rank gives us the position in an ordered set, ***kind of***.

The rank procedure is very useful and cool, but I could't find in Deedle's doc how to perform it. Is there direct way to do it in Deedle or I need to create my own extension?

I suppose I could do it using these functions:

```
SortRows(frame, key)
chunk size series
```

Comment: Deedle does not have a built-in `rank` function - I think your idea to use sorting and chunking is the best way to simulate it.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I wrote my own extension (see my own answer to this post). I tried to use the chunk function, but it turns out that you can only use chunk if the series is sorted by its key, but I needed it to chunk it when sorted by the values of a column... so I did it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own extension:

```
type Frame<'TRowKey, 'TColumnKey
        when 'TRowKey : equality
        and 'TColumnKey : equality> with
    static member denseRank column (groups:int) rankName frame =
        let frameLength = Frame.countRows frame |> float
        let chunkSize =  frameLength / (float groups) |> Math.Ceiling |> int64

        let sorted =
            frame
            |> Frame.sortRows column

        let ranks =
            Frame.getCol column frame
            |> Series.map(fun k _ ->
                int ((Frame.indexForKey k sorted) / chunkSize)
            )

        let clone = frame.Clone()
        clone.AddColumn(rankName, ranks)
        clone
```

where indexForKey is this other custom extension:

```
    // index for row with key
    // index starting at 0
    static member indexForKey (key:'K) (frame:Frame<'K,_>) : int64 =
        frame.RowIndex.Locate key
        |> frame.RowIndex.AddressOperations.OffsetOf
```

I tried this other definition hoping that it would run faster. It is slightly faster, but not by a lot; any comments on performance issues are welcomed:

```
static member denseRank column (groups:int) rankName frame =
        let frameLength = Frame.countRows frame
        let chunkSize =  (float frameLength) / (float groups) |> Math.Ceiling

        let sorted =
            frame
            |> Frame.sortRows column

        let sortedKeys = Frame.getRowKeys sorted

        let ranksArr = Array.zeroCreate frameLength

        sortedKeys
        |> Seq.iteri (fun index _ -> ranksArr.[index] <- index / (int chunkSize))

        let ranks = Series(sortedKeys, ranksArr)
        let clone = frame.Clone()
        clone.AddColumn(rankName, ranks)
        clone
```